# Browser screenshots never appear for non-Windows platforms

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm trying to use the Browser Screenshots feature eg:

http://dev.modern.ie/tools/screenshots/#http://www.microsoft.com

I've noticed that screenshots never appear for non-Windows devices e.g. Google Nexus 7 on Android 4.1.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Mike, I work on the team that manages http://modern.ie. I'll send off an email immediately to the program manager that works directly on this and see if we can nail down the root issue.

Comment: I just retried this out of curiosity, and after about 2 minutes it did load screenshots for all the devices.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to have resolved the issue, whatever it was.

When you have issues with various Edge properties, I encourage you to hit the @msedgedev folks on twitter.  They seem to listen pretty aggressively.

For future reference, links to supply feedback on Microsoft Edge:

- Bugs for Edge and IE - https://connect.microsoft.com/ie/feedback
- Developer Feedback Home -
  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer
- Developer Feedback Twitter - https://www.twitter.com/msedgedev
- Feature Suggestions -
  https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/category/18985-web-browsing

Hope that helps.  Healy in Tampa.